# Add multiple TFrame controls to TScrollBox

Tags: delphi, vcl

I'm doing a little offline shopping cart application here with Delphi and I'm stuck. I need to insert frame to scrollbox (act as shopping cart item row, where I can remove item, add quantity and so on) on product select from listview. But I can't add multiple frames there.

```
    procedure TfrmMain.lvProductsSelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem;
  Selected: Boolean);
var
  cartRow: TFrame1;
  i: Integer;
  count: Integer;
begin

  cartRow := TFrame1.Create(nil);
  cartRow.Edit1.Text := Item.Caption;
  cartRowArr := TObjectList<TFrame1>.Create;
  cartRowArr.Add(cartRow);
  count := cartRowArr.Count;
  for i := 0 to cartRowArr.Count - 1 do
  begin
    ScrollBox1.InsertControl(cartRowArr[i]);
  end;
end;
```

It's always on frame there and can't get it right. If I select product I need to insert frame, if I select another product I need to insert antoher frame. If product that I select is alredy there, then raise quantity by one.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you want multiple frames in the scroll box to end up below each other. Have you tried adding

```
cartRow.Align := alTop;
```

This would cause the rows to automatically align themselves next to each other vertically.

Comment: Thank you, it solved the problem! Now it's getting two rows at the time to scrollbox when I select item. I removed loop and change code that adds control to ScrollBox1.InsertControl(cartRowArr.Last);

Answer (score 0):

Based on the docs, you should set the parent property of the control rather than use InsertControl. Therefore the code should be:

```
for i := 0 to cartRowArr.Count - 1 do
begin
  cartRowArr[i].Parent := ScrollBox1;
end;
```

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.InsertControl